# Incorrect number of reviews displayed

Tags: support

When I go onto the main Sports site, I get a notification of outstanding reviews. Sometimes there are reviews, other times not. This has only started happening recently (after I went over 2k rep, which I'm sure is related).

Is this expected behaviour, am I missing something, or is there a bug somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Expected" behaviour for high reputation users; see [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5762/the-change-to-the-taskbar-is-massively-annoying/5763#5763) on meta.physics for the reasoning behind it.

(Personally, I think the behaviour is silly, but I don't make the decisions).

A warm welcome to the 2k club, by the way :-)

Comment: Thanks Philip - I thought it might be something like that. I agree that it's not a great user experience, but I suppose at least it's consistent. Thanks for the welcome too!